# Silverlight business application: windows authentication using IIS express not working

Tags: silverlight-5.0, iis-express

When using IIS Express and Windows Authentiction with Silverlight 5 (using silverlight business application template in VS 2012), the status bar is stuck at "authenticating..."
Switching back to the Visual Studio Developer Server, Windows Authentication works.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by applying below.

Need to update extra configurations (at IIS express level), in addition to Visual studio settings.

1. Go to MyDocuments\IISExpress\config\applicationhost
2. Search for windowsAuthentication
3. Updates:

   3.1 Under sectionGroup name="authentication" and section name="windowsAuthentication", update overrideModeDefault to "Allow". Default is "Deny"

   3.2 Under authentication >> windowsAuthentication, update enabled="true". Default is false.
4. Save and close

All projects, using Windows authentication and running under IIS express, will start running smoothly.